# 2 Conga parameters questions

Tags: conga, conga-composer

I'm oh so close to having my configuration setup but need still could use a last bit of assistance to have it perfect.

I'm calling Conga from a button.  Works perfectly.  I'm using DS7=1 so the generated document is being attached to the parent record.

1. Is there a way I can insert "Generated by Conga Composer" into the
   Description field on the attachment object record in the process?
2. Is it possible to suppress the Background generating window?

Thanks,

Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steve,

Interesting request.  Right now Conga Composer doesn't have the ability to insert text to the Attachment description field, however that is an interesting feature request.  I'll surface that as an Idea with our product team.  One easy option would be to use the &OFN= parameter and include "Conga" or something similar in the file name.

As for completely bypassing the user interface / pop-up you would have to use Conga Workflow via Outbound Messaging.

Don't hesitate to email: support@getconga.com for further assistance or insight